# I have a question about this package "firebase_ui_firestore"

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am a Flutter developer, and I am currently developing it in conjunction with Fireestore.

I happened to find this package for code simplification.

This package has reduced hundreds of lines of code.

However, if you link the fire store, there will be a charge for every data fetching, what do you think about this?

I looked it up and found that this package reads the database in real time like StreamBuilder..

Can't you make it like FutureBuilder?

firebase_ui_firestore: ^1.4.0

cloud_firestore: ^4.8.2

firebase_database: ^10.2.3

firebase_auth: ^4.6.3

I'm worried that I'll be charged a lot using this widget on the comment list page.

```dart
class _CommentScreenTestState extends State<CommentScreenTest> {

late Query<CommentModel>? _query;

@override() {
  _query = null;
  init();
}

Future<void> init() async {
  try {
    _query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('comment')
          .doc('')
          .collection('commentDeps')
          .orderBy('regDate', descending: true)
          .withConverter<CommentModel>(
            fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => CommentModel.fromMap(snapshot.data()!),
            toFirestore: (item, _) => item.toJson(),
          );
  } catch(e) {print(e);}
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(_query == null) return CustomLoadingIndiCator();
    return FirestoreQueryBuilder(
      query: _query!,
      builder: (BuildContext context, FirestoreQueryBuilderSnapshot<CommentModel> reCommentSnapshot, _) {
        if (reCommentSnapshot.isFetching) return const CustomIndicator();
        if (reCommentSnapshot.hasError) return Container();
        if (!reCommentSnapshot.hasData) return Container();
        if (reCommentSnapshot.docs.isEmpty) return Container();
        return ListView.builder(...);

}
```

Did I wirte the code in the wrong way?
I just want error handling, comfortable comment more logic and loading logic for connection.
If you have a good idea, please recommend it to me